# Mapa não funciona mais

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que usava a API do Google Maps. Ele tava funcionando normalmente, até que actualizei o Android Studio de 2.1 para 2.2 e de lá para cá, ela parou de funcionar.
O que faço para voltar a usá-lo?

Comment: QUal o erro?! Poste algum código de como você está fazendo.

Comment: Eu não vejo nenhum erro. Instalo a apk no meu celular e de lá não vejo nenhum erro!

Comment: E o que acontece então?

Comment: Quando abro o mapa, ele fica em branco, nada é mostrado! Será que tenho que ir mexer lá nos credenciais?

Comment: Provavelmente, testa sua KEY em outro lugar. veja se ela ainda está ativa

Answer (score 1):

Você pode ter que adicionar o *plugin* de serviços do Google ao seu arquivo `build.gradle`. Precisa criar um arquivo `google-services.json` para guardar o `project_id` e `api_key` em formato JSON para todos os serviços do Google. Entre no [Try Sign-In for Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start) aqui para gerar seu arquivo.

#### Detalhes

- [The Google Services Gradle Plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin)